# Straightening UV-map from STEP file

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I imported a .step file into blender (which perfecrtly with an add-on I have) but I'm having problems with straightening out the UV-map, which I need for some image textures. Is there any (quick) way to fix this? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: specificaly for selected part - Project from view

Comment: I always thought that meant something different. Thanks a lot, that was a simple one!